# Is it possible to put special pieces on a chess.com custom board?

Tags: analysis, chess-variants, online-chess, unorthodox-pieces

I would really like to create custom positions with custom pieces (and maybe even variants) to play with my friends because we have always enjoyed playing custom variants. So for example a board with the camel instead of knights. Is there a way to do this on chess.com or an equivalent website?

Comment: Are these pieces your own imported in or already a part of the website?

Comment: @HarryIguana The required pieces are all ready inside chess.com, you can see them is some variants

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most advanced diagram creator in the whole Internet is the Board Painter of Musketeer Chess. There are others, but none like this.

It has almost FOUR HUNDRED different fairy pieces for each colour (400 white and 400 hundred black), including not only an impressive zoological collection with every animal that could possibly be imagined, and with every strange object that might be thought of as a Fairy Chess piece, but also traditional pieces and special boards for Japanese Shogi, Chinese Xiangqi, Chinese Weiqi (also known as Go), and many other historical or regional Chess-like games for playing almost any variety of Chess ever invented.

The board can be made of any colours, not just black and white, and with an enormous number of rows and columns for those who, as it is my case, love playing in gigantic boards with legions of Chess men battling on them.

I have played Grand Triple Chess (a variety of 24 x 16 squares, totalling 384 squares) using this amazing diagramme creator. The game is now available in Evo Chess, but when it was not available, we used to play by the method of creating a diagramme for every move, converting the diagramme to an image, and sending the image to the opponent. It works perfectly well.

The Board Painter of Musketeer Chess is fairly complex, You can even mark specific squares and indicate moves with arrows and symbols of various forms and colours. Endless number of possibilities, but the Board Painter is not very easy to learn, which means that You will need an ample time for experimenting with it and learning how to use it correctly. Once You know its sophistication, You will have a truly impressive tool at Your disposal.

I know it in detail, therefore if You have questions, be kind to ask and with pleasure I shall help Your study. Because study You will need, do not expect to know how to use all of its incredible resources on the very first day.

A fine piece of on-line software, available [here](https://musketeerchess.net/p/tools/boardpainter/).

Comment: Welcome to [Chess.SE]! This looks a bit like an advertisement; if you are affiliated with this website, [you must explicitly state to](/help/promotion).